# Warning: expected 'int (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'int **'

Tags: c, gcc, java-native-interface, mpi

I am calling an MPI function `MPI_Group_range_incl`. Here is its signature:

```
    int MPI_Group_range_incl(MPI_Group group, int n, int ranges[][3], 
                     MPI_Group *newgroup)
```

I am confused how to pass the `ranges[][3]` argument. Below is the code I have implemented. It compiles and works correctly but gives compile time warning:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'MPI_Group_range_incl' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
int errCode = MPI_Group_range_incl(existingGroup, n, (int**)nativeOneDimRanges, &newGroup);

mpi.h:989:5: note: expected 'int (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'int **'
```

How I call:

```
int oneDimRangesLen;
jint *nativeOneDimRanges;
jboolean isCopy = JNI_TRUE;
MPI_Group newGroup;

oneDimRangesLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,oneDimRanges);
nativeOneDimRanges = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, oneDimRanges,
                                                 &isCopy);


MPI_Group existingGroup = (MPI_Group)
((*env)->GetLongField(env, thisObject ,GrouphandleID));

int errCode = MPI_Group_range_incl(existingGroup, n, (int**)nativeOneDimRanges, &newGroup);
...
more code....
...
```

Note that

```
    jintArray oneDimRanges
```

comes as one dimensional int array from JVM but it actually contains the information needed by the function `MPI_Group_range_incl` with stride of 3. So it works fine, but I just want to get rid of the warnings. Any help?

Comment: Why you´re casting to `int**` if you know that it is wrong? Cast to the type it wants, and that´s it. (edit: That does not mean it is possible to solve any array conversions with casts. But in this case, it is no problem.)

Comment: Cast to `int (*)[3]`.

Comment: @deviantfan you mean instead of int** I put int*[3] ?

Comment: What **exactly** is the return type of `GetIntArrayElements()`?

Comment: @alk Returns a pointer to the array elements, or NULL if the operation fails. ref http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html